# How to run set operation on two list columns of data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I am trying to apply intersect on two columns or say one column and one list. It works for if I have more than one group by column but not if I have only one and I am not able to understand why? It throws warning, somehow it takes list differently..

Works:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c("a","a", "b","b", "c"), b = c("PKR","AFB", "ICH", 
"PKR", "GHI"))
dt <- dt[, c :=.(list(unique(b))), by=a] 
y <- nrow(dt)
dt <- dt[, i := mapply(intersect, c, rep(list(c("AFB","PKR")), y))]


dt <- data.table(a = c("a","a", "b","b"), b = c("PKR","AFB", "ICH", "PKR"))
dt <- dt[, c :=.(list(unique(b))), by=a] 
y <- nrow(dt)
dt <- dt[, i := mapply(intersect, c, rep(list(c("AFB","PKR")), y))]

dt <- data.table(a = c("a","a", "b"), b = c("PKR","AFB", "ICH"))
dt <- dt[, c :=.(list(unique(b))), by=a] 
y <- nrow(dt)
dt <- dt[, i := mapply(intersect, c, rep(list(c("AFB","PKR")), y))]
```

But not work for:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c("a","a", "a","a", "a"), b = c("PKR","AFB", "ICH", 
"PKR", "GHI"))
dt <- dt[, c :=.(list(unique(b))), by=a] 
y <- nrow(dt)
dt <- dt[, i := mapply(intersect, c, rep(list(c("AFB","PKR")), y))]


dt <- data.table(id = c(1,2),a = c("a","a"), b = c("PKR","AFB"))
dt <- dt[, c :=.(list(unique(b))), by=a] 
y <- nrow(dt)
dt <- dt[, d :=  rep(list(c("AFB","PKR")), y)]
dt <- dt[, i := {mapply(intersect, c, d)}]
```

Could someone share how this is working exactly? Or what I am missing.

Comment: Use `Map` instead of `mapply` -- `dt[, z := .(Map(intersect, c, d))]` -- the warning you see refers to a matrix, but you want a list, I guess? `mapply` simplifies to matrix by default.

Comment: Thanks, so much it worked, but why mapply was working when I had more than 1 distinct values in group by.

Comment: `mapply` has a hard-to-predict output format because it *tries* to simplify to matrix, but when it cannot (because not all elements have the same length), it acts like `Map`, giving a list. (I pretty much always use `Map`.)

Comment: Thanks that kind of explain it didn't create matrix when length was not same and gave me correct result!